# Grails spring security save login time in user domain

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using [this](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#registeringEventListener) link if we register a call back in grails, how to access `springSecurityService` in plain groovy/java class, so that we can get the current user domain class and save the login time?

Update:

I have done this using the below:

```
appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the callback closures you can get the information from the [AuthenticationSuccessEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html).

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // handle AuthenticationSuccessEvent
   println "User id ${e.authentication.principal.id} was authenticated"
}
```